# WSGI, Rack vs NodeJS, Twisted, EventMachine

Tags: node.js, webserver, twisted, wsgi, rack

What is the advantage of having an application server vs an built-in server in the language? I understand that you can have separation of concerns (e.g. load balancing, rate limiting, static files, etc), but you can have that with a reverse proxy (like nginx) anyway, without the added complexity of dealing with another (language specific) protocol.

Asked another way - what is the advantage of WSGI or Rack, vs HTTP communication between web server and web application? (Academic question, understanding that there is a great amount of software already built on WSGI/Rack/Other Application Server Protocols)